# multi-select box page scroll

Tags: html, select

I have a multi-select box with size 3, when I scroll up using mouse **inside the box** the options scroll, as soon as the first element is at the top of the box, the page itself will scroll even though the mouse pointer is inside the box. same if I scroll down.

```html
  <div class="form-group">
  <label >Speciality<span class="required">*</span></label>
  <p style="font-size:11px;">Hold down Ctrl (windows) / Command (Mac) and click to select multiple options  </p>
   <select style="height: auto; "class="form-control"  multiple size='3' required>
                   <option value="">None</option>
                   <option value="1">X</option>
                   <option value="2">Y</option>
                   <option value="3">z</option>
      </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the code? How are we supposed to help without?

Comment: I have put the code now.

Comment: This is the default behaviour for your page if the page has an overflow and this is set as scroll. You need to use some javascript to prevent page scroll when mouse is inside the select box

Comment: Ok, but isn't this something that should not be default? I'm thinking.

Comment: I agree. But this is already a strong enhancement for input fields and has just been introduced in HTML5 so it's a new feature. Hope it will be improved in the future